# In HTML5 Spec, it seems the nested script tags are supported, so what does a real example look like?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

In HTML5 [Specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tree-construction.html#parsing-main-inhead), I read this "If the script nesting level is not zero: ...Otherwise, ...". It seems the nested script tags are supported.

But what is a real example that uses the nested script tags? like the below one?

```
<script>  
document.write("<script> alert('I\'m in your head!')</script>");  
</script>
```

Comment: It sort of explains it [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#overview-of-the-parsing-model)

Comment: Just as an observation - the example you posted wouldn't parse in HTML5. An end script tag (even if quoted) will always close the block.

Answer (score 0):

When used to include dynamic scripts, the scripts may either be
embedded inline or may be imported from an external file using the src
attribute

http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_script_tag.cfm

Comment: I think that what the original post is asking is not how to use the <script> tag, but why would you want to do something like <scirpt> some code <script> more code </script></script>

Answer (score 0):

Nested script tags are not meaningful because the contents of a script tag must be 'text':

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element

The example given is entirely legal because the 'nested' script tag is simply a text string which will be interpreted when the script itself is executed.

Modifying the document and replacing it's content like this should just replace it's current contents, though I haven't tried.

I don't see any controversy here.